# does set_error_handler catch errors that are not included into error_reporting()

Tags: php

If I exclude `E_WARNING` errors from `error_reporting()` - `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING)` will my custom error handler registered with `set_error_handler('error_handler')` be called for PHP warning errors?

I'm asking this because there is the following code in Kohana framework:

```
public static function error_handler($code, $error, $file = NULL, $line = NULL)
{
    if (error_reporting() & $code)
    {
        // This error is not suppressed by current error reporting settings
        // Convert the error into an ErrorException
        throw new ErrorException($error, $code, 0, $file, $line);
    }

    // Do not execute the PHP error handler
    return TRUE;
}
```

which checks whether the triggering the function should be processed `if (error_reporting() & $code)` whereas I would expect the function `error_hanlder` to be never triggered for errors that shouldn't be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've found the answer myself (from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)):

`It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE. error_reporting() settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless - however you are still able to read the current value of error_reporting and act appropriately. Of particular note is that this value will be 0 if the statement that caused the error was prepended by the @ error-control operator.`

**error_reporting() settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless**